# Problem with zohmg data import into hbase

Tags: hadoop, hbase, data-import

I have used zohmg and successfully created mapper, table in HBase and test-imported my data (using --local switch).
But I have problem inserting my data after mapping into HBase, this is error I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat not org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputFormat
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.setClass(Configuration.java:1034)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.setOutputFormat(JobConf.java:471)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.StreamJob.setJobConf(StreamJob.java:818)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.StreamJob.run(StreamJob.java:122)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:79)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.HadoopStreaming.main(HadoopStreaming.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:186)
```

Do you have any clues that might help me fix it? (Or maybe this i problem with Dumbo?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hadoop 0.20 introduced a new package, `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce`, and deprecated the old one, `org.apache.hadoop.mapred`.  HBase 0.20 followed suit with its map reduce support.  It looks like this code is expecting an OutputFormat for the old api, but getting the HBase TableOutputFormat for the new api.

Looks like the latest commit over at github may help this, it says "added patch for reverting to the old api."  (It also looks like there hasn't been any activity for awhile.)
http://github.com/zohmg/zohmg/commits/master

Comment: Yes, this project is not currently actively developed. Now I see, that this patch was not committed, but only *.patch file was added.

Comment: But still I can't make it work with CDH3, with patching or without.